# Using sqlite3 in adb shell error: "could not load needed library 'libncurses.so' for 'sqlite3' ... cannot link executable"

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

It seems simple enough to use sqlite3 with adb shell, according to [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sqlite3.html). But, when I try to run the sqlite3 command in adb shell, I get the error
link_image[1891]: 12565 could not load needed library 'libncurses.so' for 'sqlite3' (load_library[1093]: Library 'libncurses.so' not found)CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE.

Any tips for resolving this?

Edit: The device I'm using is a rooted HTC Evo API 16.

Comment: Unfortunately not, and I forget exactly what I was doing at that time also. I might have just edited SQLite db on local computer instead as a quick workaround.

Comment: How did you open the dB file on the computer?

Comment: There's a few different solutions for viewing sqlite, here's a good one: [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is going to be very useful (I usually open SQLite .db files directly on the CLI). But what I was (badly) trying to ask was: How did you download the whatever.db file to the PC?

Comment: You can copy any file from an Android device using `adb pull <database-file-on-device>` on your computer. The location will be in something like `/data/data/com.example.appname/db`. To get a more exact location, you can see `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` (depending on where you saved). Another option to transfer files to computer is to use a 'file explorer' app with a 'send' feature.

Comment: Ok, pull command (I'm new to Android and adb), thank you very much!